# Exceptions after update Elasticsearch to 7.0

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

After update `Elasticsearch 6.3.0` to `7.0` on my project, I have exception:

> Method not found: '!!0 Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticLowLevelClient.IndicesPutTemplateForAll(System.String, Elasticsearch.Net.PostData, Elasticsearch.Net.PutIndexTemplateRequestParameters)'.

I have updated all my libs, but issue still here. I used `.Net Framework 4.7.2`

Uninstall all elasticsearch libs

```
  var elasticSink = new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(elasticUri)
            {
                IndexFormat = indexFormat,
                ModifyConnectionSettings = s => s.BasicAuthentication(user, pass).DisableAutomaticProxyDetection()
            };

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(elasticSink)
                .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

They just released a new version of the package on 07/30. For us here, we updated the package Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch to the version 8.0.0 and it worked here. We were with the same problem here. Let me know if it's help for your problem.